# Do the JBoss attributes ActiveThreadCount and ActiveThreadGroupCount have maximums?

Tags: java, jboss, threadpool, jboss5.x

In JBoss 5, there is the mbean

```
jboss.system:type=ServerInfo
```

Which has the properties `ActiveThreadCount` and `ActiveThreadGroupCount`.

Does anyone know if there are maximum values for either or both of these properties, and if there are, how to find them out? I am happy parsing configuration files if necessary.

Looking at the source code of `org.jboss.system.server.ServerInfo`, `getActiveThreadCount` returns the number of active threads in a `ThreadGroup`, not a `ThreadPoolExecutor`; therefore there is no maximum.

Perhaps someone who really knows the innards of JBoss 5.1.0 GA would know whether all members of that `ThreadGroup` are created by a single `ThreadPoolExecutor` which obviously does have a maximum?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers!

Rich